# What does the command 21505 mean in ioctl?

Tags: linux, driver, ioctl

I have developed a character device driver for Linux. I have some functions that deal with files (in the file operations struct) such as read,write,ioctl,etc..

I realised (via the use of printks) that, after initialising the driver and creating the node, when I call the write function for the first time (which will call the open function for the first time too) the system is calling the ioctl function, with parameters:

```
cmd = 21505 
arg = 2125423388
```

What do these numbers mean and why is the IOCTL being called in this case?

Comment: 21505 is 5401 in hex and that seems to be at least TCGETS ioctl call.

Comment: `TCGETS` as called from `isatty(3) -> tcgetattr(3) -> ioctl(TCGETS)`.